# Is Sequence { $nsin(\frac{\pi}{n})$} convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

I just seen an example of sequence { $n\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$}; $n$ running from $1$
 to infinity,
 I am asked to classify it as convergent, divergent, or oscillating. 
At first time, I thought it would be increasing and not bounded above, so it will be divergent.
But when I saw its terms
they are like
$1,2,..,3.14159..,3.14159..,....$
That means larger the value of n, the value of terms are getting close to $3.14159$.
Means Can I say that the sequence is convergent?
To what value it converges?
Why is this so?

Comment: Have you learned that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$?

Comment: Have you considered it geometrically? Note that $\sin \pi/n$ is half the side of an equilateral n-sided polygon inscribed in the unit circle.

Comment: Can someone clearly tell me whats wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n\sin \pi}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \pi\dfrac{sin(\pi /n)}{\pi /n}=\lim_{t \to 0} \pi\dfrac{\sin t}{t}=\pi$

Comment: Oh yes, It was so simple.